# Pole - breaking point calculation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, material-science

I guess my problem would be easy solved by any mechanical engineer, but i'm not that one :-).
Ok i have 3 m long pole fixed on 2 points, at 50cm and 1m from bottom of pole. At top of pole is pulling force aprox. 500 kN, and can be interpreted as force along x-axis, pole is pipe 2", 3,5mm thick wall, made of steel S235JR.

My question si when will pipe bend or break, or to be precise how much force/moment it can withstand.

[image: Pipe 2" - whit force]